# What are the most important points of interface between a web developer and IT?

Tags: web-development

Some background:

My current job has be as the sole web developer for our company.  I have been given responsibility for a number of external websites, as well as our internal intranet site.

The external sites are currently hosted externally, and either created/maintained with a CMS, or custom designed by the external host.  I will be migrating the websites to our own internal server, and redesigning them using whatever tools I deem necessary (php, jquery, MySQL, etc.).

The intranet is hosted internally, but also needs a complete redesign.

Our IT is currently going through some reorganization, and historically has little experience with web technology.  I want to plan coordination with them, help develop proper infrastructure, and identify the primary channels of communication between us.

My question is: what are the main points of coordination that normally exist between development and IT, focusing on web-based development?  Given a (relatively) blank slate, what would be the ideal division of responsibilities, and primary points of direct collaboration?

I know some aspects of my particular situation may be atypical (i.e. I'll be responsible for setting up the PHP environments, source control repositories, database administration, etc.), but I'd like answers to focus more on the typical configurations, as that will be more useful to others.

Answer (score 3):

Have IT manage the web servers that will host your web applications as well as the database servers storing the related data. You do the rest (i.e. concentrate on writing and maintaining the web applications).

For communication, I would use a ticketing system to track any issues that come up with the web applications and associated infrastructure. Assign any server-specific issues to IT. Assign other issues to yourself or IT as you see fit. It's important to have a record of issues in general, especially if you are managing several web applications at once.

Develop a process, put it in writing and make sure everyone follows it. Coordination means participation, so involve the IT department in the development of a process you can all agree on.

Answer (score 1):

**IT**: Manages hardware and the Operating Systems. For example, servers, drives, backups, patches, windows users, network security, etc

**Web Developer**: Manages website content, and web hosting setup. For example, creating / maintaining webpages, creating/managing databases, IIS/Apache/Other setup, source/version control, etc